# POI cannot open a workbook that opens in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I try to open a .xlsx file in POI, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry. Is it really an excel file?
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getWorkbookDirEntryName(HSSFWorkbook.java:223)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:245)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:188)
```

I notice that the code is considering it a .xls file even though the name is .xlsx, and I am using `WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);` to open the file.

I tried renaming the file to .zip and opening in WinZip and I get an error - invalid zip file.

The file does open in Excel, and if I save it (without making a single change), then it opens correctly in POI as well.

Answer (score 2):

From what you say, which is that you have a `.xlsx` file but it's turning up in HSSF with no Workbook entry, I'm going to deduce that you have an Encrypted .xlsx file

There are basically 4 ways of handling a .xls or .xlsx file:

- Unencrypted .xls file - OLE2 storage, works with HSSF
- Encrypted .xlsx file - OLE2 storage, some records encrypted, works with HSSF if you [supply the password](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XLS)
- Unencrypted .xlsx file - OOXML (zip of xml) storage, works with XSSF
- Encrypted .xlsx file - Stored in OLE2, which holds encrypted part, which wraps OOXML, which ..... which finally works with XSSF (it's nasty)

So, what I think is happening is that you're checking the type of the file, seeing it's OLE2, then passing that to HSSF. HSSF looks for the bits it works with, can't see them, and gives up

What you need to do is [follow the instructions on the POI Encrypted Documents page](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats). Basically, your code needs to be something like:

```
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(filesystem);
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

try {
    if (!d.verifyPassword(password)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
    }

    InputStream dataStream = d.getDataStream(filesystem);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(dataStream);

    // Process XLSX file here
} catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process encrypted document", ex);
}
```

If you use the latest version of POI, it'll now throw an `EncryptedDocumentException` if you give an encrypted .xlsx file to HSSF, so you can work out more easily where you went wrong

Comment: It's protected, but not encrypted. I tried your code and got an exception that it couldnt find an algorithm

Comment: In many cases, protected = encrypted, for reasons best known to Microsoft. Could just be protected with the default password, but it'll still be encrypted

Comment: Interesting! Then why do I get an exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/ECB/NoPadding

Comment: Could be that it's encrypted in a way that POI doesn't support. Is this the file from the similar looking POI bug report from yesterday?

Comment: I didn't file a bug report

Comment: You'll either need to, or share here the file, as we'll need to look at exactly what's in it to identify why POI can't process the encryption it uses

Comment: @Gagravarr: Can you please answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771477/how-to-read-password-protected-excel-files-using-poi-with-eevnt-model?

Comment: What if password is not there and the file is locked