# ColdFusion cfspreadsheet: error occurred while reading the Excel. The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry

Tags: excel, encryption, coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

In ColdFusion 10 Spreadsheet:

I have a daily routine that reads a few Excel files and stores them in a database. I have recently started receiving a file with some  macros. The service cannot read the file. If I open and save the file then it will be read.

Anyone knows what is going on here?

Here is my code:

```
<cfspreadsheet 
    action="read" 
    src="PJM Matrix MM 36-Mo 2014-02-28.xlsx"  
    query="data" 
    sheet = "2" 
    rows="1-588" 
    columnnames="A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L">
```

Here is the error:

```
An error occurred while reading the Excel: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry.
    Is it really an excel file?.
```

Here is my excel file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71626816/PJM%20Matrix%20MM%2036-Mo%202014-02-28.xlsx

Comment: Did you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543666/poi-cannot-open-a-workbook-that-opens-in-excel) for [that error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=MACRO+Excel+POI+java.lang.IllegalArgumentException%3A++++++The+supplied+POIFSFileSystem+does+not+contain+a+BIFF8+%27Workbook%27+entry.) ? (I doubt CF supports encrypted sheets natively)

Comment: *receiving a file with some macros* Not sure that is the issue. Open the file with a .zip tool, the structure looks non-standard ie /EncryptionInfo)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the spreadsheet you are trying to upload, belongs to a BIFF version prior to BIFF8. Coldfusion doesn't support reading these files. But when you open and save, the file becomes BIFF8 version and will be able to be processed. Currently there is no fix for this.

https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10072

POI jars are responsible for reading spreadsheets in CF and they support only BIFF 8 version. Please check response for Q-6 in above url.